# How to access a container port of another container using kubernetes-plugin in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-kubernetes

i'm trying to access a exposed port from a container to another container inside the same node, but i can't figure out how to do this using kubernetes plugin in pipeline.

In my script I have created both containers and exposed the port of a database container, in the other container i'm trying to access the port 1521 of a host.

```
def label = "mypod-${UUID.randomUUID().toString()}"
podTemplate(label: label, containers: [
    containerTemplate(name: 'oracle', image: 'repo:5000/ng-oracle:latest',privileged: true, ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat', ports:[
        portMapping(name: 'oracle1', containerPort: 1521, hostPort: 1521),
        portMapping(name: 'oracle2', containerPort: 22, hostPort: 2222),
    ]),
    containerTemplate(name: 'maven', image: 'repo:5000/ng-satelites:4', ttyEnabled: true, command: 'cat')
  ]) {
        node(label) {
            stage('all') {
                container('maven') {
                    stage('test-db') {
                        sh 'curl $(/sbin/ip route|awk \'/default/ { print $3 }\'):1521'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this? ran into the same problem myself, both containers within a Pod should be accessible via their name, I have mongo and maven but my build fails due to timeout connecting to `mongo` container from maven container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a Kubernetes POD, all containers 'see each other' through localhost. Therefore, you should be able to connect to your `oracle` container from your `maven` container on `localhost:1521`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @gmc, but i have tried with localhost and it don't work!

"+ curl localhost:1521
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed

  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 1521: Connection refused"

Is there any other configuration that i have to do to make this working?

Comment: Are you sure the service is started and listening inside the container? Bare in mind that when you specify the option `command: cat` you are overriding the container's default entrypoint.